# How to calculate species contribution percentages for vegan rda/cca objects?

Tags: r, pca, vegan

I am trying to reproduce the column ("variable" in `FactoMineR::PCA`, "species" in `vegan::rda`) [contribution percentages to axes from the `FactoMineR`](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/112-pca-principal-component-analysis-essentials/) package in `vegan`. The contributions are coded in `FactoMiner::PCA` objects:

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(vegan)

data(dune)

fm <- FactoMineR::PCA(dune, scale.unit = FALSE, graph = FALSE)

head(round(sort(fm$var$contrib[,1], decreasing = TRUE), 3))
# Lolipere Agrostol Eleopalu Planlanc  Poaprat  Poatriv 
#  17.990   16.020   13.866    7.088    6.861    4.850
```

By looking at the code for `FactoMiner::PCA`, I found out that the contributions are calculated as squared axis coordinates divided by the axis eigenvalue and multiplied by 100%:

```
head(round(sort(100*fm$var$coord[,1]^2/fm$eig[1], decreasing = TRUE), 3))
# Lolipere Agrostol Eleopalu Planlanc  Poaprat  Poatriv 
#  17.990   16.020   13.866    7.088    6.861    4.850
```

I fail to replicate the calculations above using a `vegan::rda` object:

```
vg <- rda(dune)

head(round(sort(100*scores(vg, choices = 1, display = "sp", 
scaling = 0)[,1]^2/vg$CA$eig[1], decreasing = TRUE), 3))
# Lolipere Agrostol Eleopalu Planlanc  Poaprat  Poatriv 
#   0.726    0.646    0.559    0.286    0.277    0.196
```

I am obviously doing something wrong, and the discrepancy is probably due to the difference how these two packages calculate the coordinates for columns as eigenvalues for axes are quite similar (identical for my actual dataset), but the coordinates are not:

```
# vegan eigenvalue for axis 1
vg$CA$eig[1]
#     PC1 
# 24.79532 

# FactoMineR eigenvalue for axis 1
fm$eig[1]
# [1] 23.55555

# vegan column coordinates for axis 1
head(round(scores(vg, choices = 1, display = "sp", scaling = 0)[,1], 3))
# Achimill Agrostol Airaprae Alopgeni Anthodor Bellpere 
#  -0.176    0.400    0.007    0.155   -0.163   -0.097 

#FactoMineR, column coordinates for axis 1
head(round(fm$var$coord[,1], 3))
# Achimill Agrostol Airaprae Alopgeni Anthodor Bellpere 
#   0.854   -1.943   -0.033   -0.751    0.791    0.472 

# Sum of column coordinates for vegan axis 1 to illustrate the difference
sum(scores(vg, choices = 1, display = "sp", scaling = 0)[,1])
# [1] -0.796912

# Sum of column coordinates for FactoMineR axis 1 to illustrate the difference
sum(fm$var$coord[,1])
# [1] 3.867738
```

How do I calculate column/species percentage contributions to ordination axes using a `vegan` `rda`
object?

Comment: I found the solution and answered my own question. If someone has a better explanation, please go ahead and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vegan`'s unscaled (`scaling = 0`) column coordinates have equal sums of squares (i.e. 1 for each axis). You can get "column contributions" by simply squaring the unscaled coordinates:

```
head(sort(round(100*scores(vg, display = "sp", scaling = 0)[,1]^2, 3), decreasing = TRUE))
# Lolipere Agrostol Eleopalu Planlanc  Poaprat  Poatriv 
#  17.990   16.020   13.866    7.088    6.861    4.850
```

Sum of these "contributions" equals 100% as said above:

```
sum(100*scores(vg, display = "sp", scaling = 0)[,1]^2)
# [1] 100
```

Answer (score 6):

The unscaled scores in **vegan** are unscaled in the (normal) sense that their sum of squares is 1 -- independent of eigenvalues:

```
> colSums(scores(vg, choices=1:4,dis="sp", scaling=0)^2)
  PC1 PC2 PC3 PC4 
    1   1   1   1
```

I think this is documented. If you want to call these squared terms as contributions, that's OK with me. The same holds for `cca`, but there you need to study weighted sums of squares. Moreover, the *unscaled* scores for sites (`dis = "si"`) will have the same unit sum of squares: that is the idea of being unscaled. If you *scale* either species or sites, then the same relationships no longer hold for the other set of scores. In general, being unscaled means that the scores are orthonormal so that their crossproduct is an identity matrix (diagonal or sum of squares 1 and non-diagonal elements 0). For *scaled* scores these sums of squares are proportional to eigenvalues (but it may be useful to read **vegan** vignette on design decisions for `const`ant scaling of the scores).

**vegan** functions `goodness` and `inertcomp` may (or may not) give you the information you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for explanation Jari! If you could copy the solution from my answer to yours, so I can delete mine. Yours is (of course) better.

Comment: A point is that your answer claims `scaling = 0` to return *scaled* eigenvalues, but they really are *un*scaled. With unscaled we mean that they all have equal sums of squares of unity independent of their eigenvalues.

Comment: Ok, I corrected the wording. Maybe one answer is still better than two? I have no problem deleting mine, but yours does not give a direct answer to the question. If you added that piece of code from mine to yours, I could delete mine.